# How to remove space after image caption?

Tags: spacing, floats, captions

I am writing one article in which i need to write one image and its caption. I found space after caption seems to be more than normal.

```
  \begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{image1.jpg}                   
  \caption{\textcolor{gray}{\footnotesize \textit{ImageCaption}}}
  \end{figure}
   This is first text after caption.
```

How can i reduce the space between caption and text?

Comment: What other packages are you loading? If you're using [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption), perhaps setting `\aftercaptionskip` would work. Otherwise, `\intextsep` or `\textfloatsep` (see the [`layouts` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/layouts) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/layouts/layman.pdf); section **6.1 Float and text page layout**, p 25).

Comment: Yes, I am using caption package but \aftercaptionskip does not seem to be working.

Comment: If you use the `caption` package the correct command is `\captionsetup{belowskip=0pt}`. But since this is the default value something is going wrong at your document. But to find out we need an MWE from you.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: \captionsetup{belowskip=0pt} does not seem to be working fine.

Comment: *Please* include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)...

Comment: Does `\raggedbottom` help? (put it in your preamble)

Comment: am i right: you're worried about the space between the bottom of the `figure` float and the following text? -- that may not be anything to do with the caption itself (`caption` package’s `\belowcaptionskip` is zero by default, iirc).  between the bottom of the float and the following text `\intextsep` is added, which is `12pt` by default: try setting that to `0pt` and see whether that helps.

Comment: I would really suppose that someone who has asked 25 questions before would know how a question should look like and what MWE means. Just a comment: IMHO putting `\textcolor`, `\footnotesize` and `\textit` manually into the caption text shows a lack of concept. The package `caption` that you claimed you use provides a lot of `\caption` customization on the document level, so that it applies consistently to all captions.

Comment: @JLDiaz it does, but why ? consider adding as an answer

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă Apparently I cannot answer. The question was closed as duplicate. The reason `\raggedbottom` helps is that it allows TeX to use empty space at the end of each page. By default, TeX tries to align the bottom line of all pages to the same point, and this is achieved by inserting extra vertical space among some elements, such as equations, figures, captions, etc. `\raggedbottom` removes the inter-paragraph spacing and accumulates it at the bottom of the page, instead, much as MS-Word does, for example.

Answer (score 25):

A quick way would be to use `\vspace{}` with negative length as input. **However, this is not the right approach and is not recommended for use.**

Without using `vspace` the output would look like:
[image: without vspace]

Here is a MWE with `vspace` and negative length as input followed by the output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image}                   
  \vspace{-1em}
  \caption{\textcolor{gray}{\footnotesize \textit{ImageCaption}}}
  \vspace{-1.5em}
  \end{figure}
   This is first text after caption.

\end{document}
```

Note how the use of `vspace` after the figure and after the caption shrinks the space.

[image: with vpsace]

Comment: The OP gave no working example, but stated that the problematic extra space was "after [the] caption". Also, it seems bad practice to manually (and possibly multiple times) correct the spacing in the document body instead of looking for a solution applicable (once) in the document's preamble.

Comment: Thanks @lockstep. I realize that this may not be the right way to solve the problem.

Comment: If ` \begin{figure*}` is used vspace only deletes space from one column not the both