# How to have center title in listings when you have subcaption (workaournd conflict between listing caption and subcaption class)?

Tags: floats, listings, captions

I want to use **listings package** (`\usepackage{listings}`) to show a matlab code in a paper (using elsarticle class) but the title is not aligned in center below the code. This happened after I added `xleftmargin=3.5cm` and `xrightmargin=3.5cm` to add margin from left and right. If I remove these two options, title appears at the center of page! How can I have both margin and center title with listings?

I used `\centering` and `\begin{center}...\end{center}` but they didn't work.

**UPDATE:** I found out that `\usepackage{subcaption}` is the problem. without it title will be centered. But I need subcaption!

my code:

```
\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{ecrc}
\volume{00}
\firstpage{1}
\journalname{Best Journal Ever}
\runauth{S. Gerami}
\jid{}
\jnltitlelogo{Best Journal Ever}
\CopyrightLine{2013}{Published by Elsevier Ltd.}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

%%FOR MATH
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

%%I NEED THESE PACKAGED FOR FIGURES AND SUBCAPTIONs
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%%FOR CODES
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

%%FOR TABLES
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\dochead{}
\title{title of my paper}

\author[bahonar]{Sajjad Gerami}
\ead{sajjad.gerami@gmail.com}
\address[bahonar]{Faculty of Mathematics and Computer Science, Best University, Somewhere, The One Country}

\begin{abstract}
abstract text....
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{First section}
\lipsum{}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{ %
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},   % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,        % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
  breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  breaklines=true,                 % sets automatic line breaking
  captionpos=b,                    % sets the caption-position to bottom
  commentstyle=\color{mygreen},    % comment style
  deletekeywords={...},            % if you want to delete keywords from the given language
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
  extendedchars=true,              % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
  frame=single,                    % adds a frame around the code
  keepspaces=true,                 % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},       % keyword style
  language=Octave,                 % the language of the code
  morekeywords={*,...},            % if you want to add more keywords to the set
  numbers=left,                    % where to put the line-numbers; possible values are (none, left, right)
  numbersep=5pt,                   % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray}, % the style that is used for the line-numbers
  rulecolor=\color{black},         % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. comments (green here))
  showspaces=false,                % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
  showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings only
  showtabs=false,                  % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  stepnumber=1,                    % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
  stringstyle=\color{mymauve},     % string literal style
  tabsize=2,                       % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
%  title=Script 1: A program in Matlab to estimate the total area under sin(x),                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption instead of title
  xleftmargin=3.5cm,
  xrightmargin=3.5cm
}

\begin{lstlisting}[title={Script 1: A program in Matlab to estimate the total area under $\sin(x)$}]
a=0;
b=pi/2;
h=max(feval(@func,linspace(a,b,n)));
x=a+(b-a)*rand(n,1);
y=h*rand(n,1);
N=0;
f=sin(x);
for j=1:n
    if y(j)<=f(j)
        N=N+1;
    end
end
ans=N/n*h*(b-a)
\end{lstlisting}
%*****************
\lipsum{}

\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

**UPDATE2:**
I tested method proposed in following link and not worked:
[Center caption in listing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88193/center-caption-in-listing)

but then I saw [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85489/how-to-center-a-lstlisting) and edited to this:

```
\begin{figure}[thp]
\begin{center}
  \begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left]
  My Code
  Another line
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{center}
\caption{my caption or title}
\end{figure}
```

result:
[image]

It's good but the gap between box and caption is too much. I need to reduce it for good result.

**UPDATE3:**
[This link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100118/how-to-remove-space-after-image-caption) has the best answer to removing gap for just one figure.

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image}                   
  \vspace{-1em}
  \caption{\textcolor{gray}{\footnotesize \textit{ImageCaption}}}
  \vspace{-1.5em}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I get it centered. Anyway, you'd probably better use `\begin{lstlisting}[title={Script 1: A program in Matlab to estimate the total area under $\sin(x)$}]` instead of putting it inside the `\lstset`.

Comment: @karlkoeller I did what you said and got the same result! How you centered it? did you have margin and center title?

Comment: I've just used your code. Please post a complete compilable example that reproduces your issue.

Comment: @karlkoeller you are right. I was creating a simple example and I realized that I am using `caption` and `subcaption` package. when I commented it out `subcaption` title centered. But I need subcaption in my paper. I'll update the code with a simple example.

Comment: To reduce the gap, move the `\caption` command inside the `center` environment and add `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` just before `\caption`.

Comment: Did you read section 6.7 of the `caption` manual?

Comment: @MartinSchröder now I did. It says `listings` package overwrite `caption` setting and it can be overwritten back by `\captionsetup[lstlisting]{justification=centering}`. Interesting. where were you to mention this when I was like this :-S Thanks. I test it later.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 3):

Effectively, there is some incopatibility between `caption` and `listings` when you use `xleftmargin` and `xrightmargin`...

Without changing any commands from one or the other package, one thing that comes to mind is to insert the listing inside a centered minipage.

So, remove the lines

```
  xleftmargin=3.5cm,
  xrightmargin=3.5cm
```

from inside the `\lstset`

and insert your listing in your document in the following way:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[title={Script 1: A program in Matlab to estimate the total area under $\sin(x)$}]
a=0;
b=pi/2;
h=max(feval(@func,linspace(a,b,n)));
x=a+(b-a)*rand(n,1);
y=h*rand(n,1);
N=0;
f=sin(x);
for j=1:n
    if y(j)<=f(j)
        N=N+1;
    end
end
ans=N/n*h*(b-a)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

Thus, the following MWE

```
\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}

%%I NEED THESE PACKAGED FOR FIGURES AND SUBCAPTIONs
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{caption}  % no need because it is loaded by subcaption.
\usepackage{subcaption}

%%FOR CODES
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{title of my paper}

\author[bahonar]{Sajjad Gerami}

\begin{abstract}
abstract text....
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{First section}
\lipsum{}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{ %
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},   % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,        % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
  breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  breaklines=true,                 % sets automatic line breaking
  captionpos=b,                    % sets the caption-position to bottom
  commentstyle=\color{mygreen},    % comment style
  deletekeywords={...},            % if you want to delete keywords from the given language
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
  extendedchars=true,              % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
  frame=single,                    % adds a frame around the code
  keepspaces=true,                 % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},       % keyword style
  language=Octave,                 % the language of the code
  morekeywords={*,...},            % if you want to add more keywords to the set
  numbers=left,                    % where to put the line-numbers; possible values are (none, left, right)
  numbersep=5pt,                   % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray}, % the style that is used for the line-numbers
  rulecolor=\color{black},         % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. comments (green here))
  showspaces=false,                % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
  showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings only
  showtabs=false,                  % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  stepnumber=1,                    % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
  stringstyle=\color{mymauve},     % string literal style
  tabsize=2,                       % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[title={Script 1: A program in Matlab to estimate the total area under $\sin(x)$}]
a=0;
b=pi/2;
h=max(feval(@func,linspace(a,b,n)));
x=a+(b-a)*rand(n,1);
y=h*rand(n,1);
N=0;
f=sin(x);
for j=1:n
    if y(j)<=f(j)
        N=N+1;
    end
end
ans=N/n*h*(b-a)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\lipsum{}

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Just some remarks:

1. I've removed some code from your MWE since I didn't know where to get the package `ecrc`.
2. the package `caption` doesn't need to be loaded since it is already loaded by the package `subcaption`.
3. I don't know if you are using `title` instead of `caption` for a specific reason. If the reason is to get rid of the word "Listing" inside the caption you can do the following:

   a. put the following line in the preamble:

   ```
   \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Script}
   ```

   b. replace

   ```
   \begin{lstlisting}[title={Script 1: A program in Matlab to estimate the total area under $\sin(x)$}]
   ```

   with

   ```
   \begin{lstlisting}[caption={A program in Matlab to estimate the total area under $\sin(x)$}]
   ```

Comment: The `ecrc` package must be called to make the CRC functionality available. It's in the Elsevier template. You used `\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}` and `ecrc` is in it! Your answer is very good. As you can see I have a workaround with figure for this issue. Your remarks is so much teaching. Thank you.

Comment: @sajjadG Remember that inserting the listing inside a `figure` causes the listing to float. Also, you will have it listed in the List of Figures. If you want this behavior, then use your workaround, otherwise, I'd suggest you to use the code in my answer.