# Reduce space after table caption in amsart class

Tags: tables, spacing, captions, amsart

I have looked both the answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100118/how-to-remove-space-after-image-caption) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26220/control-spacing-around-table-caption), but could not fix my problem.

A minimal working example is the following

```
\documentclass{amsart}[11pt]

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{caption} 
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cccc}
   1 &2 &3 &4\\ \hline
   1 &2 &3 &4\\ \hline   
   1 &2 &3 &4\\ \hline
   1 &2 &3 &4\\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\caption{}\label{tab:1}
\end{table}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

As it stands, there is too much white space after the caption and above the paragraph below. I can remove it with a command like

```
\vspace{-2em}
```

But I probably should refrain from doing that.

Comparing the different document classes between `amsart` and `article`, it looks like that `amsart` moved the caption upward immediately blow the table, without trimming the overall space.

What I have tried:

1. Setting `captionsetup{belowskip=0pt}` does nothing;
2. `\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}` trims some space below the caption but killed all of them above the table;
3. `\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-8pt}` moves the caption inside the table.

Your kind help is appreciated.

Comment: `amsart` expects captions to be above tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `amsart` class expects captions to be above tables.

If you prefer them below, use `caption` features:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\captionsetup[table]{position=below}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
1 &2 &3 &4\\ \hline
1 &2 &3 &4\\ \hline
1 &2 &3 &4\\ \hline
1 &2 &3 &4\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{This is the text of the caption}\label{tab:1} 
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Note that the syntax is `\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}` (you have the optional argument in the wrong place).

[image]